# Add custom file to jar path in spark-submit cli

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am creating spark jar file with following scala code embedded in it:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object GetRequest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val api_credentials = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")
    val username = api_credentials.getString("pi.api.username")
    val password = api_credentials.getString("pi.api.password")
}
```

While submitting the jar,it is not able to find `application.conf` file which is inside path `C:\Users\abc\Desktop\ApiSparkJob\resource`.How to mention the same in spark-submit command in cli?

Answer (score 0):

The resource file bundled inside a jar wouldn't be available for each spark worker therefore you need to pass the file using --files argument

--files application.conf

If your resource manager is YARN, refer to the below code

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import java.io.{BufferedReader, File, InputStreamReader}
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object GetRequest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    val yarnStagingDir: String = System.getenv("SPARK_YARN_STAGING_DIR")
    val confFile: Path = new Path(yarnStagingDir.concat("/application.conf")
    val fs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
    val br: BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileSystem.open(confFile)))
    val api_credentials: Config = ConfigFactory.parseReader(br).resolve()
    val username: String = api_credentials.getString("pi.api.username")
    val password: String = api_credentials.getString("pi.api.password")
    br.close()
  }
}
```

// Don't close the filesystem fs.close() as it ends your job since same filesystem is used to access hive warehouse directory.